# Laravel Model Relationship. which one?

Tags: php, laravel, model, rss, relationship

Hey there So I should start by say I was given this DB to work with. so not sure what relationship they used. What I need to be able to do eventually is get the name of the categories assigned to the articles.

basically it look like this `articles <> article_categories <> categories`

article_categories being the connector

articles
`|ID|header|body|ect...|`

categories
`|ID|parent_group|name|`

article_categories
`|article_id|category_id|`

So I thought that maybe it was a `hasManyThrough` but only got errors. This also could be that I did the arguments wrong.

What I tried first was inside the articles model (got an error from this)

`public function category(){
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\categories' , 'App\article_categories' ,'article_id' , 'category_id');
}`

Hope i explain my situation. Do i need to use `has many through` or am I over complicating this?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need for `hasManyThrough`

`belongsToMany` is what you need.

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\categories' , 'article_categories' ,'article_id' , 'category_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your article_categories model

Create a function for categories

```
public function categories(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories' , 'category_id');
}
```

And the same for articles

```
public function articles(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Articles' , 'article_id');
}
```

And just an advice use the singular for MODELS and i dont know if its ok to say "plural" for MIGRATIONS:

MIGRATION : Articles , MODEL : **Article**

the same for

MIGRATION : Categories , MODEL: **Category**

Hope this can help you! Good luck